# JMeter HTML Dashboard shows NaN for the total row when Generate Parent Sample is checked in all the transaction controllers

Tags: performance, jmeter, reporting, nft

I have a JMetre scenario Where I use Below structure

```
Thread Group
--Transaction Controller 1
----Module Controller 1 --> Simple Controller 1
--Transaction Controller 2
----Module Controller 2 --> Simple Controller 2
--Transaction Controller 3
----Module Controller 3 --> Simple Controller 3
TestFragment
-- SimpleController 1
---- Req 1
-- SimpleController 2
---- Req 2
-- SimpleController 3
---- Req 3
```

When I do not check the "Generate Parent Sample" on at least one of the Transaction Controllers the generated HTML report shows some values tot he TOTAL tab of the Statistics table in the Dashboard. (Didnt check if the value is correct, but there is some value as below)

[image]

When all of the Transaction Controller are checked for "Generate Parent Sample", the Statistics table of the generated dashboard shows "NaN" and unrealistic numbers.
[image]

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should set the following property:

```
jmeter.save.saveservice.subresults=true
```

If you don't want the child samplers to be present in the dashboard/statistics table you can filter them out:

[image]

Example command:

```
jmeter -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.subresults=true -Jjmeter.reportgenerator.exporter.html.series_filter="^(Transaction Controller 1|Transaction Controller 2|Transaction Controller 3)(-success|-failure)?$" -n -t test.jmx -f -l result.jtl -e -o dashboard
```

If you want to make the changes permanent - put the above values into *user.properties* file

More information:

- [Apache JMeter: Properties Reference](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html)
- [Configuring JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)

Comment: Thanks @dmitri-t, I have updated my jmeter.properties with jmeter.save.saveservice.subresults=true. But Still the report generated shows NaN.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever the properties you use,the Transaction Controllers result lines in the jtl file will start by "Number of samples in transaction" for the column "Response Message", and that's why the results are filtered out of the computation for the total.

If you edit one of the value of Response Message in the jtl (replacing "Number of samples in transaction" by anything else, you'll see that the total will take the value of this line, as it will not be filtering out anymore.